# docker COPY is not copying the files

Tags: docker

```
FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80

COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Am trying to run an Angular app with the following docker configuration.  It does work, but I can't see the files/directory that was suppose to be copied in that location "/usr/share/nginx/html" which is super confusing.  The directory only contains the default index.html nginx created.

Does it store it in memory or something since the files are not there but it does fetch my website properly.

Build:

```
docker build -t appname .
```

Run:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 appname
```

Comment: Can you add the `docker run` command you're using to the question?

Comment: added the build and run

Comment: Are you sure they're not there? What makes you think they are not if the website is running?

Comment: went too /usr/share/nginx/html/ and ran "ls" the directory only contains index.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the COPY destination path is not the path on disk server but its the path inside the image of the docker.  Which explains why i cant see my files on the server disk.